# Change last word after space in a dafaframe column

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I am working on a data frame that contains computer names and I am trying to anonymize the computer names. Here is an example of the dataframe, I am working with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'computer_name': [u'LENOVO 09 X32H0GB', u'LENOVO vmhsbpmh613.xyz.biz', u'Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 XKF2S75', u'HP  ppesfesxb203.corp.123.com', 'IBM SoftLayer 13 L89P4567']})
```

Here is what it is required to anonymize it.

1. Pick the first set of strings from the RIGHT after the first SPACE from the RIGHT ..
   eg : for "LENOVO vmhsbpmh613.xyz.biz" it would be "vmhsbpmh613.xyz.biz"
2. After getting the first set of strings from the RIGHT eg "vmhsbpmh613.xyz.biz", remove all characters from the first Dot (.) , which would give "vmhsbpmh613" and if there are no Dot(.) then retain only the last set of string , Please note it is important to remove only the strings after dot (.) from first set of strings from the RIGHT, otherwise like in this example " Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 XKF2S75 " it would result in removing everything after Dot " Dell Inc. "
3. Lastly replace the first 3 characters with xxx , like xxxsbpmh613

Here is how the output should look like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'computer_name': [u'LENOVO 09 xxxH0GB', u'LENOVO xxxsbpmh613', u'Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 xxx2S75', u'HP  xxxsfesxb203', 'IBM SoftLayer 13 xxxP4567']})
```

I hope, I was able to articulate the requirement clearly, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['computer_name'].str.replace(r'\S{3}(\S+?)(?:\.\S+|$)', r'xxx\1')
```

---

```
0                   LENOVO 09 xxxH0GB
1                  LENOVO xxxsbpmh613
2    Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 xxx2S75
3                    HP  xxxsfesxb203
4           IBM SoftLayer 13 xxxP4567
Name: computer_name, dtype: object
```

**Regex details**

- `\S{3}` : Matches any non-whitespace character extactly `3` times.
- `(\S+?)` : Capturing group matches any non-whitespace character between 1 and unlimited times but as few times as possible (lazy match)
- `(?:` : Begining of non-capturing group
- `\.` : Matches `.` character
- `\S+` : Mathes any non-whitespace character
- `$` : Asserts position at the end of line
- `)` : Ending of non capturing group

See the [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/ez8hfz/1)

Comment: Thanks @tdy I'm not sure if its any better but I'm still trying to improve the pattern, there are lots of corner cases where this pattern would fail :-)

Comment: @ Shubham, this worked thank you ... would you mind explaining the regex... that would really help me with the learning

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for regex. Here's some options:

```
# select all chars until reaching a period
df['computer_name'].str.extract('([^.]*)')

# alternatively, replace all chars after a period with an empty string (delete it)
df['computer_name'].str.replace('\..*','')

# For your 3rd requirement, select all non space chars at the end of a string and format the result using match groups.
df['computer_name'].str.replace('([^\s]{3})([^\s]*$)', r'xxx\2',)
```

Comment: @ Royce, thank you, it almost worked... only issue is with Row ID 3, 'Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 XKF2S75" it is giving out 'Dell xxx" , i would required 'Dell Inc. PowerEdge R910 xxx2S75", like in have mentioned in point 2 of my question